# Обрезать все атрибуты img

Tags: php, html

Есть строка

```
<img src="images/stories/2017/12/1-49.jpg" _mce_src="images/stories/2017/12/1-49.jpg" alt="" title="Петр САРУХАНОВ — «Новая»" class="caption" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" _mce_style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
```

Как обрезать все атрибуты что бы строчка осталось такой

```
<img src="images/stories/2017/12/1-49.jpg">
```

Comment: каков контекст? где это, откуда и куда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Вариант из предыдущего моего ответа:

```
$str ='<img src="images/stories/2017/12/1-49.jpg" _mce_src="images/stories/2017/12/1-49.jpg" alt="" title="Петр САРУХАНОВ — «Новая»" class="caption" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" _mce_style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">';

echo preg_replace('~(?<!src=)"[^"]+"[^">]*~', '', $str);
```

> Результат:

```
<img src="images/stories/2017/12/1-49.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

можно не не обрезать атрибуты, а найти `src` и подставить его куда надо. Поскольку информации о том, какими средствами и в каком контексте вы работаете с этой строкой нет, то одним из решений может быть с использованием регулярок:

```
$str = '<img src="images/stories/2017/12/1-49.jpg" _mce_src="images/stories/2017/12/1-49.jpg" alt="" title="Петр САРУХАНОВ — «Новая»" class="caption" style="display: block; margin

$out = preg_replace('/.*\bsrc="(.*?)".*/', '<img src="$1">', $str);

print_r($out);
```